# Mapbox Studio labels repeated

Tags: labeling, mapbox

I am new to Mapbox studio so I may be overlooking something very basic - I have a polygon shapefile that I am trying to style - I want one label per polygon but am getting more - often four labels.  I have tried using the buffer-size and text-repeat-distance options but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: you get multiple labels because the shapes in your shapefile are "multiparts", i.e. a MULYPOLYGON. Think of italy, the geometry may be composed of distinct polygons, one for mainland, and then a bunch more for the islands.